# Is it possible get Client tenant user role as claim on app tenant ad token

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I have an Auth AD Tenant(Multi-Tenant) and multiple Client AD Tenant(Single-Tenant) App.

Is it possible to get a user role that is set on their own single-tenant client ad app in a claim on token get from Auth AD by sign-in?

If possible what is the configuration? I am using the MSAL library to handle AD on my Angular Application.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure whether this helps you but you should be able to define an application role in your multi-tenant application registration and map user groups to that role using a role assignment.
See: [Add app roles to your application and receive them in the token](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-add-app-roles-in-azure-ad-apps?WT.mc_id=AZ-MVP-5003203)